# JIDE Table column cell styles getting applied to other jide tables as well

Tags: java, swing, renderer, jide

I have two instances of Jide `SortableTables`. Each table having some string columns.

For columns in table `A` , applied cell style to display a tool tip and change the horizontal alignment to Right. But the same style is applied to other columns in Table B as well. I am not using an custom cell styles for table `B`. Somehow the same tool tip data which is shown in table `A` is applied to Table B as well.

Any help on this is appreciated.

Example:

Added the below cell style code for column A to display the tool tip.But the tooltip is coming for all columns . And the columns for another table which does not use this code at all.

@Override
    public CellStyle getCellStyle(int row,int column) {

```
  Object obj = getValueAt(row,column);
  CellStyle style = new CellStyle();
  if (obj != null) {
    style.setToolTipText(obj.toString());
   }
  return style;
}
```

Comment: Post [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) for help.

Comment: AFAIK Jide has own Renderer, see API/docs for more info

Comment: How does a renderer applied for one column effects other columns in a different table. Please bare my ignorance